# Oracle: ON DELETE CASCADE causing trigger recursion

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, cascade

Let's take as example this two tables: **Customer** containing the customers and **Product** containing the products bought/used by the customers.

Every product references a customer trough the foreign key **CustomerID**,  which corresponds to the primary key of the table Customer (they also have the same name).

When a customer is deleted all the products which referenced that costumer are deleted: **Product.CustomerID** has the attribute **ON DELETE CASCADE**.

Now let's say that a customer on the base should at least have a product:
when a product is removed, if it is the last product of a costumer then the costumer must be removed as well.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER RemoveCustomer
AFTER DELETE ON Product
BEGIN
        DELETE FROM Customer
        WHERE CustomerID IN (
                SELECT c.CustomerID
                FROM Customer c
                LEFT OUTER JOIN Product p
                    ON p.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
                GROUP BY c.CustomerID HAVING COUNT(p.CustomerID) = 0
        );
END;
/
```

This solution seems to be natural to me but Oracle dislikes it.
At every DELETE of a product I get the error:

```
ORA-00036: maximum number of recursive SQL levels (50) exceeded
```

This even if the DELETE wouldn't cause a program to be removed.

Surprisingly, this syntax works just fine:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER RemoveCustomer
AFTER DELETE ON Product
BEGIN
        FOR my_row IN (
                SELECT c.CustomerID
                FROM Customer c
                LEFT OUTER JOIN Product p
                    ON p.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
                GROUP BY c.CustomerID HAVING COUNT(p.CustomerID) = 0
        ) 
        LOOP
                DELETE FROM Customer WHERE CustomerID = my_row.CustomerID;
        END LOOP;

END;
/
```

Could somebody explain why is this happening?

**EDIT:**

Here there is a working example:

```
CREATE TABLE Customer (
    CustomerID INTEGER                 PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE Product (
    ProductID INTEGER                 PRIMARY KEY,
    CustomerID INTEGER,
    CONSTRAINT fk_Customer FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID)
                                        REFERENCES Customer
                                        ON DELETE CASCADE
);


INSERT INTo Customer (CustomerID) VALUES (0);
INSERT INTo Customer (CustomerID) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTo Customer (CustomerID) VALUES (2);
INSERT INTo Customer (CustomerID) VALUES (3);
INSERT INTo Customer (CustomerID) VALUES (4);
INSERT INTo Customer (CustomerID) VALUES (5);
INSERT INTo Customer (CustomerID) VALUES (6);

INSERT INTO Product (ProductID, CustomerID) VALUES (0, 0);
INSERT INTO Product (ProductID, CustomerID) VALUES (1, 0);
INSERT INTO Product (ProductID, CustomerID) VALUES (2, 1);
INSERT INTO Product (ProductID, CustomerID) VALUES (3, 2);
INSERT INTO Product (ProductID, CustomerID) VALUES (4, 3);
INSERT INTO Product (ProductID, CustomerID) VALUES (5, 3);
INSERT INTO Product (ProductID, CustomerID) VALUES (6, 3);
INSERT INTO Product (ProductID, CustomerID) VALUES (7, 4);
INSERT INTO Product (ProductID, CustomerID) VALUES (8, 5);
INSERT INTO Product (ProductID, CustomerID) VALUES (9, 5);
INSERT INTO Product (ProductID, CustomerID) VALUES (10, 6);


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER RemoveCustomer
AFTER DELETE ON Product
BEGIN
        DELETE FROM Customer
        WHERE CustomerID IN (
                SELECT c.CustomerID
                FROM Customer c
                LEFT OUTER JOIN Product p
                    ON p.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
                GROUP BY c.CustomerID HAVING COUNT(p.CustomerID) = 0
        );
END;
/


/* This request will produce the error */
DELETE FROM Product WHERE CustomerID = 3;
```

Answer (score 2):

It is surprising, but it appears that a cascading delete statement on `products` **always** occurs after a delete is performed on `customers` - even if no customers are deleted.  For example:

```
SQL> delete customer where customerid = 9999999;
delete customer where customerid = 9999999
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00036: maximum number of recursive SQL levels (50) exceeded
ORA-06512: at "TTEST.REMOVECUSTOMER", line 2
...
```

With your second version of the trigger, the `for` loop body is never executed when there are no customers with no products, so the delete of `customers` never occurs and the infinite loop is avoided.

Comment: With the second version of the trigger, even when the loop is executed there is no recursion. Is that normal ?

Comment: @TTK - the loop is executed but finds no matching rows the second time, so the delete inside the loop is *not* executed again.

Comment: @Alex Poole - If I'm right, lets suppose only one customer needs to be removed: the first time the loop is executed it does a DELETE on the customer. The DELETE should execute again the trigger because of the cascading delete statement. At this point we have one recursion level but this time the trigger will not enter inside the loop as the only customer was already removed. Am I right?

Comment: Tony, It's a statement level trigger. It'll be fired per statement. It doesn't matter whether a `where` condition evaluates to true or false

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov I'm not talking about the trigger, I'm talking about the cascaded delete.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov - the surprising bit isn't the trigger firing whether or not a product is deleted; it's that the cascade delete on customer (from the product FK) still does a nominal product delete (and hence fires the trigger indirectly) even when no customers are deleted?

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes. 'on delete cascade' forces statement-level trigger to fire on child table even if no rows are deleted from parent table - it's a statement level trigger. Row-level trigger won't fire.